# How Get ID of the record from Map

Tags: apex, community, map, salesforce-id, collection

I want to add Map id into Method Parameter
And required only one I'd not Set

```
Map<Id,fsCore__Transaction_Parameter_Field__c> obj =new Map<Id,fsCore__Transaction_Parameter_Field__c> ([Select id,fsCore__Field_Name__c from fsCore__Transaction_Parameter_Field__c]);
```

I Want id of Above into below Method Parameter

```
fXe__Transaction_Parameter_Setup__c testTransactionParameter = fXe.TestOroFinancial.getParamSetup(transactionParamFieldId,'Test Param Name'); // only required single id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the `Ids` i.e. keys from map, you can use the `Map's` `keyset()` method, this will return the `Set<Keys>`. As you have a map of `Map<Id,fsCore__Transaction_Parameter_Field__c>`, doing `obj.keyset()` will return you `Set<Id>`

So to pass Set to your method, you simply have to do

```
fsCore__Transaction_Parameter_Setup__c testTransactionParameter = fsCore.TestHelperFinancial.getTestTxnParamSetup(obj.keyset());
```

Note that it will return the `Set<Id>` and not single `ID`, so make sure that your method accepts `Set<Id>` and not single `Id`

If you are sure that you will get only one record, then you can convert the `keyset` to `list` and then use the index to pass the first element to your method.
For that, you can use below code

```
List<Id> listOfIds = new List<Id>(obj.keyset());
fXe__Transaction_Parameter_Setup__c testTransactionParameter = fXe.TestOroFinancial.getParamSetup(listOfIds[0]);
```

You can get more information on [Map](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm) on the mentioned link.

Comment: Not Accept Set<Id>, Required only one id

Comment: Your map can have multiple records i.e. it can have multiple Id's, in that case, how do you decide on which Id should be passed from the set of Ids you have ?

Comment: Need only one Id for testClass,

Comment: Updated the answer with the relevant code to pass the first element to method from map's keyset. That should solve your problem.

Comment: It Show System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Comment: Are you sure, you are getting any values in `obj`, it must be null or empty.

Comment: How to fix that

Comment: If it's a test class, you will have to insert a record in `fsCore__Transaction_Parameter_Field__c` in test method and then your code should follow

Comment: DML Operation Not Allowed

Comment: You will have to debug your code or I would advice you to post a separate question for this. Your question should be specific to one problem, so that people can help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94335/discussion-between-vijay-ganji-and-tarsbir-singh).

Comment: Thanks for your Time, I Solved it

Comment: That's great Tarsbir !